# Not possible to see ubuntu 12.04 from the update manager

Tags: 12.04, installation

Using Ubuntu 12.04, I cannot see any update from my update manager. It gives me the message "check your internet connection"

Comment: If you're connected to the internet, is it via a method recognised by the network manager

Comment: Are you onnected to the internet via some 3g/Wireless Broadband dongle that uses a software(generally aka crossplatformui) ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use the internet, and your network is working, then try this: Open Update Manager, press Settings button and on te first tab, change the server where it says "Download from: ". I had the same issue, and for me it was automatically set to Germany. I selected Main server, and it's fine now:

[image]

Comment: If you select "Other" from the dropdown, then "Select Best Server" it will choose the one that is fastest for your location.

Comment: It cannot find the best server