# Why is downloading repository updates so slow?

Tags: 11.10, updates, update-manager, cache

Okay, I have Ubuntu version 11.10 and I wish to upgrade to 12.04. Whenever I open the Update Manager and click "Check," it has taken literally over an hour to download the cache. I cannot update without checking the cache; attempts in the console (as suggested  [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1905677)) have failed. 
What do I do in order to update without waiting over three hours to download the entire cache? Or how do I get it to download quicker? 
EDIT: Saw [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141744/not-possible-to-see-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-update-manager), it provided no help. Just false hope. Oh, and no, my internet works just fine; normally I have a 600kb/s download rate. No dial-up here.

Comment: Try changing your server. to do that go-to ubuntu software center and edit-software sources, then in the ubuntu software tab, select "download from" to another server or "Other", then it will automatically select the best server for your location

Comment: I tried that, and it gave me hope! But then it shot me down. D: Thank you though.

Comment: What just happened? still slow? may be you have thousands (or millions) of repositories installed, isn't it?

Comment: I literally just installed this Ubuntu today, about 7 hours ago. :P I have absolutely nothing on here but the operating system and stock software. I unchecked everything except "Canonocial Supported" in Software Sources, which I assume would be the OS update. And yes, still slow.

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/135818/the-size-of-apt-get-update-lists-is-too-big/ to see if this is the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: No. No such console output.

Comment: Try this upgrade procedure from [Official Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again later and it worked. So it solved itself. I think it was probably just my internet having a hiccup, but only to this computer. Which is weird.